# Face detection differenet sizes of faces using openCV haarcascade_frontalfacedetection

Tags: opencv, face-detection

I'm trying to figure out the best face detection algo for me.I've already tried different methods to do so, but the detection isn't working so well.Im using openCV haarcascase(trying out the different kinds).

My question is:how do i set the size of the face detection so it will detect Big faces(Close up on the person) and also small faces(Zoom out) with the same code.

When I'm using the following command im getting true for facedetecting even when there aren't faces in the image:

```
faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections, 1.1, 3, 0 | Objdetect.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE,
                new Size(**50,50**), new Size());
```

But if I'm using it with new Size(**200,200**) for example im unable to detect faces in pictures where the faces are "small".

Does anyone have an idea how can I make the detection work for both small and big faces without "inventing" faces that aren't there?

Answer (score 0):

*detectMultiScale* function has parameters min and max face size. Don't forget to consider you image size before choosing face size. Try smth like that

```
double max_face_size_percent = 1;
double min_face_size_percent = 0.15;

cv::Size min_face_size = cv::Size(grayImage.size().width * min_face_size_percent,grayImage.size().height * min_face_size_percent);
cv::Size max_face_size = cv::Size(grayImage.size().width * max_face_size_percent, grayImage.size().height * max_face_size_percent);

detector.detectMultiScale(grayImage, detected_faces, (double) scale_factor, 3, 0, min_face_size, max_face_size);
```

You can choose the biggest face found after that with code like this

```
    double best_face_metric = 0;
    std::vector<cv::Rect>::iterator bestFaceIterator = detected_faces.begin();

    for (std::vector<cv::Rect>::iterator it = detected_faces.begin(); it != detected_faces.end(); ++it) {
        double curr_face_metric = it->width + it->height;
        if (curr_face_metric > best_face_metric) {
            best_face_metric = curr_face_metric;
            bestFaceIterator = it;
        }
    }

    cv::Rect_<double> bestFace(bestFaceIterator->x, bestFaceIterator->y, bestFaceIterator->width,
                               bestFaceIterator->height);
```

Or implement any solution of any kind to choose correct faces by yourself

Comment: thanks.the code was helpful.but still the detection isn't so good..think ill use CNN

Comment: Can you give an example image where you think face detection quality isn't good?

Comment: can i upload picture here? it happens in many pictures.thanks for ur help

Comment: Upload them to any kind of storage & paste link here